# How do I aggregate activerecord model data for a specific time period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, aggregate

I'm collecting data from a system every ~10s (this time difference varies due to communication time with networked devices).  I'd like to calculate averages and sums of the stored values for this activerecord model on a daily basis.  All records are stored in UTC.

What's the correct way to sum and average values for, e.g., the previous day from midnight to midnight EST?  I can do this in sql but don't know the "rails way" to make this calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
range = 1.day.ago(tz.now).beginning_of_day..1.day.ago(tz.now).end_of_day
total = Model.sum(:column, :conditions => {created_at >= range})
```